# map function pointers to specific numbers at runtime

Tags: c, function, mapping

I have a problem that i can even start to work on because i don't get it how can be done.

So we have a code

```
int test_handler() {
    printf("Test handler called\n");
    return 1;
}

// Test your implementation here
int main()
{
    register_irq_handler(30, &test_handler);
    do_interrupt(29); // no handler registered at this position, should return zero
    do_interrupt(30); // calls handler at position 30, expected output: Test handler called

    return 0;
}
```

I need to make those functions  register_irq_handler, do_interrupt(29).
But i have no clue how to start, i am looking for a little help to send me on the right direction.

How i store 30 to point to this function when we don't have a global variable to store that "connection" or i am missing something.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but have a feeling that an array of function pointers might help.

Comment: ok thx that help a little, will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without a global variable (why would having a global variable be a problem?).

You probably need something like this:

```
// array of 30 function pointers (all automatically initialized to NULL upon startup)
static int(*functionpointers[30])();    

void register_irq_handler(int no, int(*fp)())
{
  functionpointers[no] = fp;
}

int do_interrupt(int no)
{
  if (functionpointers[no] != NULL)
  {
    // is registered (!= NULL) call it
    return (*functionpointer[no])();
  }
  else
  {
    // not registered, just return 0
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer**

This is non tested non error checking code just to give you an idea.

Comment: thank you for your time, but i worked it out, something like your answer above, made a globale function pointer arrays and then just write simple code. just this part 'fp' i used '*(&fp' but how i see it is same.

Comment: Yes, `fp` and `&fp` is strictly the same.